# What is a quarter wave flange in waveguide?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waveguide

I have been searching about a quarter-wave flange online. But I could not find a single website about the principle of its operation. Can someone give me an idea of its operation or where I can find more information?

Comment: Where have you come across this term?

Answer (score 1):

Flanges on wave guides are the connecting surfaces, which are secured together to assemble longer wave guides. The "quarter-wavelength" flange as a channel cut into it that is 1/4 wavelength deep. This channel serves to reduce the effects of impedance mismatches and so on. We sometime call them "stubs", name for the short lengths of open-ended conductor placed near the connectors.